# how can you travel through pages in a browser with back and forward buttons without losing the pages' states in NextJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, browser-history, next.js

How do you recover a past state when coming back to previous page (when using the browser's back button) in NextJS? Or in general, how do you recover a state when travelling between pages back and forward using browser's back and forward buttons?

I have a project where I am showing lots of gameshots in a grid ("gameshots" are something like Pinterest pins). In order to not have large waiting times when getting data from Sanity, I don't fetch it all at once and then store it in `this.props`, but in smaller batches and that's why they are stored in `this.state`.

**This is my situation:**

- Use loads the `/game` page
- Page gets 30 thumbnails from Sanity database, puts them into state as `this.state.gameshots` and renders them
- User clicks on a thumbnail and the url changes to `/game?gameshotIndex=14` (btw this is the real url but it says `/gameshot/d6fg8a456g` in the url bar)
- When the url changes, a modal window is shown with a gameshot post in it: `this.props.url.query.gameshotIndex && <Modal> ... </Modal>`
- User taps on a tag link inside the modal and goes to `/tag/d65g4d56gff4g6jfg`
- User clicks the browser's back button, and gets an error because the state at `/game` is lost and the page therefore doesn't have `this.state.gameshots` needed to show the modal. If they were loaded at once and stored in `this.props.gameshots` it would work – but then you would have to load *all* the gameshots at once, even if there was 100000000 of them – which means huge TTFB and slow page loading.

So my question is: how can you travel through pages in a browser with back and forward buttons without losing the states?

Comment: You need to persist the state somewhere that isn't affected by page transitions. So either the URL, a cookie, or local storage on the client side; or a database on the server side. You then need to have your component intercept the browser's history back event, and then restore the state from your persistent store.

Comment: how do you load thumbnails from Sanity database and save them into this.state.gameshots? Can you share your code please.

Comment: @iurii https://www.dropbox.com/s/sjywho5hf43uqe2/Screenshot%202018-12-19%2016.29.48.png?dl=0

Comment: @MarekMinor I'm more interested in what lifecycle method you do this fetch.

Comment: @iurii Oh! it's an async function called _getGameshots_. If `this.state.loadMoreGameshots` is true, then I show a `VisibilitySensor` component with a spinner svg in it. If this sensor component shows up, I fire the _getGameshots_ function: `<VisibilitySensor onChange={(e) => this.getGameshots(`...`, e)}>`. That means I always fetch them after mounting the whole page.

Comment: I think you need to move your initial getting data into `componentDidMount` lifecycle method. So this way if user clicks browser back or forward button and lends on the `/game` page, the `componentDidMount` method will be fired and the request to get data from Sanity database will be executed. After request is done you will populate the `state` with all the needed information for the page to work.

Comment: you can improve your function to get data with some cache as well (e.g. localstorage etc)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the `localStorage.setItem('images', this.state.gameshots)`, and store what you need. 
When the user get back you can use `localStorage.getItem('images')` get this data and show to the user. This gonna avoid to do another request to get the images. 
I hope that's solve your problem. :D

Comment: Thank you for this idea! I already tried to use the local storage but it didn't work quite well. I am using a component called *Gameshots* throughout many pages and after I stored the gameshots in the local storage for the first time, they showed up everywhere and nothing new got fetched. 

That's why I was trying to work with browser history, so the state is stored in all the phases of the history. But I couldnt get that working becasue nextjs handles history state.

Is there some kind of limit as to how much information you can store in local storage? What if run out of memory?